# multiplicities of irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $G'$ be a subgroup. Let $\rho$ be a one-dimensional group of $G'$. Then define $\psi$ to be the induced action of $\rho$ - $\psi:= Ind_{G'}^G \rho$ Is there any general statement how to now anything about the number of irreducible representations that occur in a decomposition of $\psi$?

Comment: Putting certain restrictions on what $G'$ can be does give you restrictions on the number of irreducible representations. An interesting (and not too difficult) case is when $G'$ is index two in $G$. In this case, the induced representation (even if $\rho$ is not one dimensional) is either irreducible or splits into two irreducible representations that are either the same or dual to each other.  Fulton and Harris has a nice section on this. I don't know how much you can say in generality, except of course to give a silly upper bound on the number of irreducibles (the index of $G'$).

Comment: Thanx. I will look into Fulton Harris. I think that if $\rho$ is the trivial representation, then I can deduce something: I think that in this case the induced representation is equivalent to the representation given by $G$ acting on the cosets $G/G'$

Comment: Could you please give me a reference for this index two case?

Comment: Fulton and Harris, "Representation Theory: A First Course". Section 5.1 and pages 63-67.